# JSON major mode complaining about valid JSON file

Tags: json

I am editing a dead simple JSON file:

```
{
   "foo": "bar"
}
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Doing a `C-h m` I see the following minor modes running alongside JSON mode:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption                    
Column-Number File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock                                 
Global-Hl-Line Global-Linum Js2 Line-Number Linum Mouse-Wheel Openwith                    
Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark
```

The following problem is reported when the cursor is on `:` character:

```
missing ; before statement
```

The entire `"bar"` string value is also highlight red.
Is the problem related to `js-lint` running alongside JSON?

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. Consider reporting it to the maintainer of the JSON support library you are using (which you don't mention, although we can see `js-lint` in the mode line). Did you try adding a `SPC` char before the `:` (shouldn't be needed, obviously - just a thought).

Comment: @Drew `SPC` makes no difference. This is embarrassing but I don't know what `js-lint` means. Looking at my `.emacs` it appears I am using `json-mode`: https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode/blob/master/json-mode.el. How can I get more information about the major mode employed (like `C-h m` does for the minor modes)?

Comment: `C-h m` tells you about both major and minor modes. `C-h f json-mode` tells you about it also, and provides a link to the file that defines it. In that file it is likely that you will find contact info for the maintainer. But you already have that from the GitHub page for the library. Contact Josh Johnston with a recipe to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Turns out I'm using js2-mode as minor-mode for js-mode

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'js2-minor-mode)
```

Everything is ok after remove above code from my .emacs.el

Another option is to add js2-minor-mode only if it's not json-mode

```
(add-hook 
  'js-mode-hook
    '(lambda () 
      (unless (eq major-mode 'json-mode) 
              (js2-minor-mode))))
```